# Deriving a Web Crypto asymmetric key from user password

Tags: javascript, jwt, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric, webcrypto-api

I am developing a web application where users must have asymmetric key pairs. There is no backend storage, and I want users to be able to transfer their keys to other devices without having to transfer files, so the key pairs must be derived deterministically from a string the user can enter manually. (The strings will be app-generated, not user-created passwords.) The app uses the [`jose`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose) NPM module (which internally uses Web Crypto) for JWT cryptography. The module does not provide a way to derive keys, but Web Crypto does - however, the [`crypto.subtle.deriveKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey) function can only derive symmetric keys. I found [Cryptico](https://github.com/tracker1/cryptico-js), which can do this, but I would need a way to convert the Cryptico key into a Web Crypto key after derivation, and Cryptico can't export the keys as far as I can tell. Is there any other way to deterministically derive asymmetric key pairs that can be used with Web Crypto?

Comment: *cryptico* can export the key with [`.toJSON()`](https://github.com/tracker1/cryptico-js/blob/master/lib/cryptico.js#L2161) as JSON, which can be converted to a JWK and thus imported by the [*WebCrypto API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey#json_web_key). However, *cryptico* seems to be quite inflexible, e.g. [3 is used fixed as public exponent](https://github.com/tracker1/cryptico-js#key-generation).